Cancellation in polynomial composition
Let $k$ be a field. Suppose $P,Q,R\in k[x]$ satisfy $P\circ Q=P\circ R$. What can we conclude about $Q$ and $R$?
It may not be the case that $Q=R$; for example, if $P=x^2$, any polynomials $Q,R$ with $Q=-R$ satisfy the given condition. More generally, translates of $P=x^n$ show that any $Q$ and $R$ that satisfy linear relation of the form $Q+a=\omega(R+a)$, where $\omega$ is a root of unity, may show up as solutions to the above.
Are there other solutions? Can we classify all pairs $(Q,R)$ that show up?

Other obvious solutions: $P$ constant, $Q,R$ arbitrary.

One can suppose $k$ alg. closed. If $P$ has degree $1$, this forces $Q=R$. If $P$ has degree $2$, write $P(x)=(x-a)(x-b)$. Then $P(x)-P(y)=(x-y)(x+y-a-b)$. So the condition is $(Q-R)(Q+R-a-b)=0$, hence $Q=R$ or $Q=-R+a+b$. Maybe in higher degree the factorization of $P(x)-P(y)$ helps. Of course this accounts as "translates of $x^n$ + constant".

@YCor, thanks for the remark, I meant to assume that $P$ is non-constant.

Let me note that, in a way, the example of quadratic polynomials does not generalize the ones I gave, since in fact any quadratic polynomial is (up to scaling) a translate of $x^2$.

Degree 3, char. not 3. One can suppose that $k$ is alg. closed, and (up to translation, adding a constant and multiplication by a nonzero scalar) that $P=X^3+aX$. Then $P(X)-P(Y)=(X-Y)(X^2+XY+Y^2-a)$, so $P\circ Q=P\circ R$, $Q\neq R$ reads as $Q^2+QR+R^2=a$. Let $u,v$ be the nontrivial cubic roots of $1$. Then $(Q-uR)(Q-vR)=a$. If $a=0$ this means $Q\in{uR,vR}$ (and in general if this occurs, then $u,v$ are in the ground field). If $a\neq 0$ this means that for some $t,s\neq 0$ we have $Q-uR=t$, $Q-vR=s$, so $s+vR=t+uR$ i.e. $(v-u)R=t-s$, which is impossible.

Degree 3, char 3. If the sum of roots is zero, the above applies but eventually yields $(Q-R)^2=a$, so $Q=R+t$ with $t^2\in{0,-a}$. If the sum of roots is nonzero, up to homothety, translation, scalar multiplication and adding constant, we can suppose $P=X^3-X^2$. So for $Q\neq R$ we get $(Q-R)^2=Q+R$. Write $Q=R+S$. This rewrites $S^2=2R+S$, i.e., $R=(S^2-S)/2$. That is, every pair $(Q,R)=((S^2+S)/2,(S^2-S)/2)$ works and these are the only solutions $Q\neq R$.

It is fine to assume $k$ has characteristic $0$ (or rather, that $k$ has large enough characteristic in terms of the degree of $P$). So the degree $3$ case still confirms the wishful thinking that $Q$ and $R$ should be linearly related...

Suppose $P\circ Q=P\circ R$, $Q\neq R$. So $n\deg(Q)=\deg(P\circ Q)=\deg(P\circ R)=n\deg(R)$, hence $\deg(Q)=\deg(R)$. Let $d$ be this common degree. If $d=0$, the discussion is clear, so assume $d\ge 1$.
Let $n\ge 1$ be the degree of $P$. We suppose $n1_k\neq 0$ (which is automatic in char. zero).
We can suppose that $P$ is monic and (up to translate, using $n1_k\neq 0$) that the sum of roots is zero. Say $P=X^n+\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}a_iX^i$. Let $c_i$, $0<i<n$, be the $n$th roots $\neq 1$ of $1$. Then
$$P(X)-P(Y)=(X-Y)\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(X-c_iY)+\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}a_i(X^i-Y^i)/(X-Y)\right).$$
From the above formula and $Q \neq R$ and since $k[X]$ is a domain we get
$$-\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(Q-c_iR)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}a_i(Q^i-R^i)/(Q-R).$$
The right-hand term has degree $\le (n-3)d$. Since the $c_i$ are pairwise distinct (because we assume $n1_k\neq 0$), all but at most one of the $Q-c_iR$ have degree $d$. If the possible last one is nonzero, the left-hand term has degree $\ge (n-2)d$ and hence we have a contradiction.
We are left with the only possibility that one factor on the left is zero, i.e., $Q=cR$ for some $n$-th root of unity $\neq 1$. We then have $P(R(X))=P(cR(X))$, and using the surjectivity of $R$ (working in an algebraic closure), we deduce $P(X)=P(cX)$, which means, $q$ being the order of $c$, that $P(X)=F(X^q)$ for some polynomial $F$.

Conclusion: when $k$ is a field, $P$ a polynomial of degree $n$ with zero degree $n-1$ term and $n1_k\neq 0$, the solutions to $P\circ Q=P\circ R$ are:

$Q,R$ constants on which $P$ takes the same value
for $q\ge 1$, $Q=cR$ with $c$ primitive $q$-th root of unity, $P=F(X^q)$.

Without assuming that the sum of roots is zero, the latter case rewrites: for some $q\ge 1$, some primitive $q$-root of unity $c$, and some $s\in k$ and $F\in k[X]$, we have $P=F((X-s)^q)$ and $Q-s=c(R-s)$.

The picture is more complicated when $n1_k=0$ is allowed; for instance in char $p$ the polynomial $P(X)=\prod_{i=1}^p(X-i)$ satisfies $P(X)=P(X+1)$.

I'm not following the part with the degree estimates.  Where did the $/(Q-R)$ in the denominator come from and why did the top summation change to $n-2$?  Also doesn't your conclusion contradict your earlier analysis that allowed for $Q = -R + a + b$ in the quadratic case?

@JackHuizenga $(Q^i-R^i)/(Q-R)$ is a shorthand for $\sum_{p+q=i-1}Q^pR^q$ (for instance for $i=3$ this is $Q^2+QR+R^2$). Since the largest $i$ is $n-2$ and $Q,R$ have degree $d$, this indeed has degree $\le (n-3)d$.

In the formula for $P(X)-P(Y)$, the summation should have a denominator of $(X-Y)$ as well.  The upper index in the next formula should be $n-1$.  Then if $Q \neq c_i R$ for all $i$ the degrees in the next formula are $\geq (n-2)d$ on the left and $\leq (n-2)d$ on the right.  Equality means $Q - c_iR$ is constant for some $i$.  Very nice!

@JackHuizenga Thanks for pointing out the typos. Indeed I assume that the degree $n-1$ term of $P$ vanishes (I messed up with two versions of my draft...). This is hopefully fixed now. And equality means $Q-c_iR$ is zero (not only constant) for some $i$.

Oh OK.  The assumption that the sum of the roots of P is zero should be included in the final conclusion as well.

@JackHuizenga Indeed. I modified accordingly.

This is very neat!
